# Fresh install of Windows 7. Windows Update has required 13 update -> restart cycles

Tags: windows-7, windows

Please note: 
I have installed SQL Server 2012 and VS 2013, I understand why this happens. My question however is there a script I can run that does something like this.

```
On System Start Up(Check For Update())
If True  
Update and Restart
If False
Stay On or Sleep (I don't really care).
```

I don't mind the number of restart and updates but IT has taken me almost 2 days to get this thing set up again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, see if the ZTIWindowsUpdate.wsf script included in the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit will do it. You may have to strip down parts of it since you're not doing a whole lite touch deployment, but this script you're looking for has already been written by Microsoft.

- [Download MDT](http://www.microsoft.com/mdt)

**FROM THE SCRIPT:**

> Installs all needed updates (drivers, patches, service packs, etc.)
>   from the Windows Update/Microsoft Update site or WSUS server,
>   rebooting as required until no more updates are needed.

**See Also:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180265/automatically-update-windows-fully